# How to string split an empty string in Go

Tags: arrays, string, go

In Python if I do...:

```
parts = "".split(",")
print parts, len(parts)
```

The output is:

```
[], 0
```

If I do the equivalent in Go...:

```
parts = strings.Split("", ",")        
fmt.Println(parts, len(parts))
```

the output is:

```
[], 1
```

How can it have a length of 1 if there's nothing in it?

Comment: Demonstrated here https://play.golang.org/p/heJXcjerIN

Comment: Oh my, I just learned that its length is 1 in C++ too. For all these years I didn't know that. But why didn't I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of `strings.Split` is a slice with one element - the empty string.

`fmt.Println` is just not displaying it.  Try this example (notice the change to the last print).

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    groups := strings.Split("one,two", ",")
    fmt.Println(groups, len(groups))
    groups = strings.Split("one", ",")
    fmt.Println(groups, len(groups))
    groups = strings.Split("", ",")
    fmt.Printf("%q, %d\n", groups, len(groups))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/rVwQqBn4Mh)

This makes sense.  If you wanted to split the string `"HelloWorld"` using a `,` character as the delimiter, you'd expect the result to be `"HelloWorld"` - the same as your input.

Comment: I noticed that it's actually the same in JavaScript. `("".split(',')).length` is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only get that result if both strings are empty:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   parts := strings.Split("", "")
   fmt.Println(parts, len(parts)) // [] 0
}
```

Which is documented:

> If both `s` and `sep` are empty, Split returns an empty slice.

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Split

Answer (score 3):

If you're used to Python's behaviour in **str.split**, you'll find a tiny wrapper around **strings.Split** helpful.

```
func realySplit(s, sep string) []string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return []string{}
    }
    return strings.Split(s, sep)
}
```